# In delete operation the api always deletes the last json object for any username or password provided?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Whenever I check the delete operation in postman than it always deletes the last element of the array. I want a particular element to be deleted.

Code:

```
app.post('/delete-user', (req, res)=> {
    users.splice(users.indexOf({ username: req.body.username, password:req.body.password}, 1))

    res.send(users)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Description):

> `indexOf()` compares `searchElement` to elements of the Array using
>   [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators) (the same method used by the `===` or triple-equals
>   operator).

Since you're using an array of objects it won't find the exact object because you're creating a new one and `indexOf` will always return `-1`.

When a negative index is used in `splice` it will remove from last the element.

You shold use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) instead, this way you can compare the objects properties and find the index.

```
app.post('/delete-user', (req, res) => {
    const index = users.findIndex(u => u.username === req.body.username && u.password === req.body.password)
    if (index === -1) {
        res.status(404).send('Not Found')
        return
    }
    users.splice(index, 1)
    res.send(users)
})
```

Comment: can it be done using the splice() method only or by doing some changes in the code of splice() itself.

Comment: I guess you could also use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) but you need to assign the results to the `users` variable because `.filter` doesn't change the original list